# Regex Match and exclude if contains word before match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have the following case.
In a log there is multiple hashes that can be extracted with the following regex

```
\b[a-fA-F\d]{32}\b
```

In this example we have 3 hashes that will be matching with the previous regex, but I want to exclude the ones that the field is named 'link' and 'value'

```
u'closed_by': {u'link': u'https://test.test.com/api/now/table/sys_user/175f7cc0d7989d87bc43e322c42c8da8', u'value': u'175f7cc0d7989d87bc43e322c42c8da8'}, u'sensor_name': u'175f7cc0d7989d87bc43e322c42c8da8'
```

I tried the following regex but didn't work, should be matching the last hash 'sensor_name'

```
(\b[a-fA-F\d]{32}\b)((.?!'link':\s\S+\')\,|(.?!'value':\s\S+\')\},)
```

**Note: this is only an extract of the original log, the match should be to anything that is a hash except the fields 'link' and 'value' following to 'lin', could be multiple fields named 'value'

Can someone help me to know what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern - any key words you want to avoid can be added to the lookbehind

`(?<!link|value)': u'([\da-zA-Z]{32})`

Comment: Thanks for the response, the thing is that there could be more fields that contain a hash, I only want to exclude the field 'link' and 'value', those are the only ones that I want to exclude, could exist even more fields with a hash, not only 'sensor name'

Comment: Does this pattern work as expected? `(?<!link|value)': u'([\da-zA-Z]{32})` - I'm assuming the `u` and the single quotes `'` will always be present...but it works (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/NYvs1e/1))

Comment: @Thefourthbird Very true! But that old answer was NG anyway, so it's gone now ;)